# Who is the current user

Tags: mailmerge, navision

I am using the Mail Merge feature of Navision and would like to be able to add the name of the user who is invoking the mail merge. If this information is stored in a Navision table, I can call it out and add it to the template.

Answer (score 1):

The current NAV user can be accessed using the **USERID** global variable (always defined in NAV objects, doesn't need to be defined by you).